# Sharpening a Knife on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat

If one sharpens a knife on Shabbos, have they transgressed an issur d'oraisa or an issur d'rabbanan?

Comment: If you did it on purpose I think it's deoraita. Why would accident matter? You mean it's a davar sheino mitkavein? It's misaseik?

Comment: I only noted that it was done by mistake because the way I typed the question to begin with I was able to submit it to do the "quality" of it. Which I don't understand how this system is judging the quality but that's a different story. The fact that it was done b'shogeg was agav...I wouldn't even had mentioned it if the shailo would have been accepted as it was...

Comment: Yehoshua, one can easily add other things to extend the length of the question (like explain what the terms means that you are using).

Comment: @SethJ fixed....

Comment: We should tell @DoubleAA.

Comment: Do you mean sharpening or honing?

Comment: @EliLansey, ''hone'', ''verb'', ''transitive'', To sharpen on a hone; ''hone'', ''noun'', A whetstone used for giving a fine edge to cutting tools, esp. razors. (Both from the OED online.) I'm nto sure I understand your question: are you asking whether Yehoshua is asking specifically about sharpening on a rock versus sharpening on anything else?

Comment: @msh210 As I understand it, honing straightens a bent end without removing any metal. This improves a sharp knife's performance, but won't help a dull knife. Sharpening (i.e. on a whetstone) is used to actually remove metal, restoring an edge to an otherwise dull knife.

Comment: And, FWIW, honing is often part of the standard usage of knives, done on a regular basis, often each time before using a knife. Sharpening is done only when the edge has been dulled.

Comment: @SethJ an additional way to add both length and quality to this question would be to add some background on why the asker assumes the sharpening is forbidden and why he suspects it may be de-oraita or derabanan.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the nature of the knife and how sharp it was to start with. If it is a knife that can only be used once it is sufficiently sharp and you sharpen it, the *issur* is *de'oraita* and it falls into the category of *makkah bepatish*. If it is a knife that does not require sharpening and you have merely done something with it that inadvertently caused it to be sharper, that is only a problem - and only according to some authorities - if doing so is the sort of thing that you would normally do during the week. If it is, you have violated the rabbinic prohibition of *shevut*. If it is not, then you have not done anything.

Comment: This is a good answer, but can be vastly improved with sources.